# How Can I Show My Custom admin module's field's data in frontend (in a popup) in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, wysiwyg

I have a **custom module admin side** created by me via an extension of module creator.

My module has some fields and one **field** is type editor i.e. the field having **WYSIWYG editor**.
I want to fetch its data whatever it contains Image or Text or Both and show it in a pop.

**Data Stored in database like** :

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test-image.jpg"}}" alt="" />
Welcome to our store.
```

Let me suggest how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data using following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/tablename')->getCollection();

foreach($collection as $_data){

    // do your job here 
}
```

Or use direct mysql query:

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "select * from table_name";
$result = $read->fetchAll($sql);
foreach($result as $_data){

    // do your job here 
}
```

Here is the way to print short code of text area :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($yourContent); ?>
```

Comment: Its working, Thanks.. I also use this but In wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

To call data in frontend you can simply call your model

If you have Specific ID

```
$model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_model')->load('id');
$model->getFieldName(); 
//or
$model->getData('field_name');
```

If You want to call Collection

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_model')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $row){
     $row->getFieldName()
}
```

In Case Of WYSIWYG Editor Data You need to proccess the data first

```
$wysiwygData = $model->getFieldName();
$htmlContent = Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($wysiwygData);
echo $htmlContent;
```